# peekService() returns null even though the service is running, if the service is restarted by the system after OOM kill

Tags: android, android-service

I'm starting a service using

```
startService(new Intent(this, RelayService.class));
```

and then the service starts an alarm using

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SyncAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + SYNC_EVERY_MS, SYNC_EVERY_MS, pi);
```

and then BroadcastReceiver `SyncAlarmReciver` is trying to get the service using

```
RelayServiceBinder relay = (RelayServiceBinder) 
    peekService(context, new Intent(context, RelayService.class));
```

It all works fine until the service is restarted by the system after application gets killed when other applications need more memory. After restart, the service relaunches the alarm using the same code, but `peekService()` returns null. Through debugging messages, I see that `context` in the service and in the broadcast receiver is the same, as well as RelayService object, i.e. these objects are the same objects in memory. How can I solve this problem?

If it helps, here are links to the three pieces of the code mentioned: [main activity](https://github.com/oakkitten/weechat-android/blob/sync/weechat-android/src/main/java/com/ubergeek42/WeechatAndroid/WeechatActivity.java#L107), [service](https://github.com/oakkitten/weechat-android/blob/sync/weechat-android/src/main/java/com/ubergeek42/WeechatAndroid/service/RelayService.java#L110-L113), [broadcast receiver](https://github.com/oakkitten/weechat-android/blob/sync/weechat-android/src/main/java/com/ubergeek42/WeechatAndroid/service/SyncAlarmReceiver.java#L12).

P.S. I know that **the service is running continuosly** because I'm watching the process closely and see it running fine and not restarting in any way, and also because I see that connection it opens before launching the alarm does not get interrupted.

Comment: See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/yiq_XIzFoS4

Comment: I use `peekService()` because I only want to communicate with the service if it's running. If it's not, I can just turn the alarm off. I guess it makes more sense to use `peekService()` in this case, isn't it? and.. oh. i see that the service just doesn't have the IBinder object..

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by JesusFreke, the problem is that `peekService()` can only return an *existing* `IBinder` object. As the service is restarted by the system and there's no `Activity` that would bind to the service at this point, the `IBinder` object does not exist yet. So a `null` is returned. It's a shame that documentation misses this fact entirely.

As I definitely didn't want to start the service if it wasn't running, using `startService()` seemed a bad idea, so I resorted to quering a static attribute of the service (which was there anyway).